# COUNT DUPLICATE RECORDS IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need a query to count the duplicate records,

For Example

```
table name -customer
===================

customer_id-col name
222
111
222
222
111
122
```

output would be

```
customer_id   count

222              3
111              2
222              3
222              3
111              2
122              1
```

i tried this query

SELECT customer_id,count( customer_id ) c
FROM customer
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING c >1

output is

customer_id   count

```
222              3
111              2
122              1
```

Is this possible Thanks in advance

Thanks
Raja

Comment: First show us what you have tried so far post your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT T.customer_id,S.duplicate_count FROM
    (
    SELECT customer_id,count(customer_id) AS duplicate_count
    FROM yourtable group by customer_id
    HAVING (duplicate_count > 0)
    ) AS S Join yourtable On S.customer_id = T.customer_id
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/691c5/2)**

**OP:**

```
 customer_id       count

    222              3
    111              2
    222              3
    222              3
    111              2
    122              1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer_id,count(1) as count
from customer
group by customer_id
```